# Where is the help for OneNote?

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-onenote-2010

I'm using Microsoft OneNote 2010. I see the ribbon (Draw). I see "Lasso Select", "Panning Hand" an various 'pens'. I want to know how to use them. I hover the cursor over them - nada. I click shift-F1 over them - nothing. I click F1, I get bingged. I input "Lasso Select" - I get "Search results for: Lasso Select - No results returned for Lasso Select." Their own tool, and no results.

I go to Microsoft to complain. Getting directed through support options that query me about my license and finally offer to connect me to a support person for $300.

$300? For "lasso select"? Or to allow me to complain why at its 10th incarnation one can't use Office Help? Come on. Come ON!

Am I missing something? Is my system mis-configured? Shouldn't there be a fast way to reach explanations and descriptions for simple questions about what ribbon buttons do?

Comment: @DragonLord I'm not complaining about the cost of customer support. What I question is the need for me to go to customer support to get a clue about what a ribbon item does. Why no F1? What am I missing?

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote-help/ and could not find what you were looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel your pain, as this isn't just a OneNote aggravation, since Office shares help.

If you hit F1, it should open a Help Windows that will (probably) lead you to MS' on-line help, with a Bing search bar on it.  If that's what you mean by "I get bingged"...

I've only got 2007 on this machine, but it's the same annoyance..

Here's the help Window, with similar (lame) results:

[image: On-line help window]

On the bottom, you can change it from On-line to Off-line (local) help:

[image: On-line Toggle]

Pick "Show content only from this computer".

Then use the Search field at the top of the window, and you get (slightly) better results:

[image: Offline Help]

You can also search within the result pages by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>.

In the end, the only place I actually FOUND a description of the Lasso was in the "What's New for OneNote 2007", which is in the on-line help as well:

> **Lasso selection** Use the Lasso selection mode in OneNote with your Tablet PC pen to quickly and accurately select ink strokes for easier
>   formatting or conversion to text.

So in the end, the Office help is below par these days (IMO).  I often find the off-line help a little less annoying than the on-line, but usually end up searching both anyway, plus Google. :)